# List<Interface> add method is not working C#

Tags: c#, interface

I have inteface with some properties including the `IRequestBodyModel`.

```
public interface IRequestHeaderModel : IWorkflow
{
    /// Other properties
    ICollection<IRequestBodyModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

implenting the the `IRequestBodyModel`.

```
public class Header : IRequestHeaderModel 
{
   /// Other properties
   ICollection<IRequestBodyModel> IRequestHeaderModel.Items
   {
       get { return this.Items.Cast<IRequestBodyModel>().ToList(); }
       set { this.Items = value.Cast<MyRequestBodyModel>().ToList(); }
   }
   public ICollection<MyRequestBodyModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

then I create an abstrct the will user the object

```
    public abstract class AbstractQuery<HeaderObject, BodyObject> 
        where HeaderObject : IRequestHeaderModel, new()
        where BodyObject : IRequestBodyModel, new()
    {
        public virtual HeaderObject GetByID(IDbConnection connection, string requestID)
        {
             connection.Query<HeaderObject>
             {
                 //sql command
                 new[]{typeof(HeaderObject), typeof(BodyObject)},
                 obj=>{
                    HeaderObject header = (HeaderObject)Convert.ChangeType(obj[0], typeof(HeaderObject));
                    BodyObject body = (BodyObject)Convert.ChangeType(obj[1], typeof(BodyObject));
                                         
                    HeaderObject headerEntry;
                    //check the header dictionary if the header is already include else get the header
                    //other codes
                    if (body != null)
                    {
                        if (headerEntry.Items.Where(x => x.ID == body.ID).FirstOrDefault() == null)
                            headerEntry.Items.Add(body); //having issue the .Add(body) is not adding and still returning empty list
                    } 
                 }
             }
        }
    }
```

implementing the abstract:

```
public class Material : AbstractQuery<MaterialRequestHeaderModel, MaterialRequestBodyModel>{....}
```

My problem now is that the item is not adding the body. When I debug it, the add is being triggered in the  `ICollection<IRequestBodyModel> IRequestHeaderModel.Items`. what is the problem here and how can I solve it.

Comment: This code doesn't compile, please provide the actual source code. Secondly, this line:
`get { return this.Items.Cast<IRequestBodyModel>().ToList(); }`
Is createing a brand new list every time. Adding to this won't affect the list you get the next time you call `get`. `ToList` creates a new list.

Comment: See previous comment. Your property returns a new `List<T>` object every time it's called, so the original list being stored can never be modified via the property. See duplicate for the exact same problem in someone else's code.

Comment: I don't see any declaration of headerEntry in your code, could you provide codes more completely?

Comment: @ekke then how can I pass the data and be editable?

Comment: @EpicChen Already corrected the question above.